# Expected number of succesfull outcomes

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a retail shop there are **21000** different types of items offered for sale. In the shop can enter customers only in pairs of two. From each pair, one person randomly select **3 items** to purchase and the other **6 items**. If at least one item is chosen in common by both persons in the pair, then it is considered a successful outcome.

Question: After **300 pairs** of customers made their purchases, what is the expected number of successful outcomes?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I would start by calculating the probability of one success. In fact, I would start by calculating the probability of a failure! How many ways are there to make the selections (with no restrictions)? And how many ways are there to make such selections that the two customers don't choose anything in common?